# Selecionar últimos registros por ordem crescente

Tags: mysql, sql

Sei que existe muitos tópicos com este assunto, mas nenhum conseguiu me ajudar até o momento.

Estou precisando selecionar os últimos 8 registros de forma que fiquem organizados por ordem crescente.

Exemplo dos registros: `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10`

Exemplo com a seleção: `3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10` (últimos 8 registros).

Tentei assim `SELECT * FROM (tabela) ORDER BY (id) ASC LIMIT 8`

Só que assim está selecionando desde o inicio, ou seja `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8`

Answer (score 3):

já consegui resolver rsrs ficou assim:

`SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM "tabela" ORDER BY "id" DESC LIMIT 8) AS t1 ORDER BY t1."id"`

Lembrando que o que está entre as aspas duplas devem ser alterados de acordo com a estrutura da tabela...